# jQuery function prevents media queries to trigger

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a few media queries in my CSS to change some properties of HTML elements. One of this element is a div called `.downloads` and one of the properties which is changing is the height of `.downloads`.

```
@media (max-width: 764px) {
  .downloads {
      height: 500px;
  }
}
```

I also have a jQuery function which manipulates the height of `.downloads` on another action the user does.

```
$('.downloads').animate({'height': 250}, 500);
```

Problem is, that after the jQuery function, the media queries do not work anymore. I assume that it is, because `height` got placed inline after the jQuery function got triggered.

```
<div class="downloads" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

Is there any idea for this problem? Thanks

Comment: You could add `!important` to css rule to override jquery inline one.

Comment: as @emmanuel said, you need to use `!important` because jQuery styles the DOM inline and as inline styling (by default) has the highest priority, it's the style that takes effect

Comment: but when I put an !important to every media query the jQuery function does not work anymore, means it does not change the height if the function is called!

Comment: @supersize - What did you expected to happen?

Comment: @LcSalazar is this an ironical question? I want my function to work, and the media queries to work.

Comment: No @supersize, it's not ironical. How will both work? If JQuery is animating it to `250px`, when do you expect the `500px` to be applied?

Comment: @supersize - Let me rephrase... What triggers this animation? Perhaps you want the animation to be effective only when not meet the media queries?

Comment: @LcSalazar a buttonclick, similar to a slider. But on media query change the slide should change to given height inside the media query css.

Comment: So @supersize, you want to animate the element up and down when the screen is normal, but to remain fixed in `500px` when on a smaller screen?

Comment: @LcSalazar I want to animate the element up and down no matter which size the screen is atm, but on a media query change it remains to the value the media query has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I get what you're trying to do...

You want to animate the element up and down, but to remain fixed in `500px` when on a smaller screen.
So, you should not be using JQuery, as it will add inline styling to the element, and you'll not be able to control mix it with the media queries rules...

Instead, add/remove a class that will have the `height` animation, and toggle it with JQuery. Then, you can disable the class properties on the media query rule:

[**Something like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/La2aozv6/2/)

CSS:

```
.downloads {
    height: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.downloads.change {
    height: 250px;
}

@media (max-width: 764px) {
  .downloads,
  .downloads.change {
      transition: none;
      height: 500px;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.downloads').toggleClass('change');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a class instead and use jQuery UI "add class" method - http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

```
.small-height{
  height: 250px;
}

@media (max-width: 764px) {
  .downloads, .small-height {
      height: 500px;
  }
}
```

And JS:

```
$('.downloads').addClass('small-height', 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
@media (max-width: 764px) {
  .downloads {
    height: 500px !important; //<--
  }
}
```

this will override JS's inline styling

Comment: but then it seems that the jQuery function does not have an effect anymore. When I do this, it does not change the height with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I read the entire question and some few comments from the top . As you want your both **css** and **jQuery** to work , I think that's not possible . You can have either style at a time not both . I think you want something like this

**CSS**

```
   @media (max-width:764px){
         .downloads{
              height:500px !important;
         }
    }
```

**SCRIPT**

```
   if($('.downloads').length>1){
        $(this).removeClass('downloads');
        $(this).animate({'height':250},500);
      }
    else 
        $(this).animate({'height':250},500);
```